# How can I remove a delay when trying to disable duplicate submit for a large form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit

I am trying to disable duplicate submit clicks on a large form with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#loading').hide();
  $('form').bind('submit', function (e) {
     $('#loading').show();
     $(this).find('input:submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

I also tried just:

```
  $('input:submit').click(function () {
     $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  });
```

However, there is a noticeable delay - several seconds - between the time the submit is clicked, and the time the button is disabled.

Is there a way to remove this delay, or at least determine the cause?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a *really* large form (and forgetting UX) try using ID's/attribute selector syntax to lookup the submit button. It might be having a hard time working it's way through the DOM with the selector you are using.

Note [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector):

> Because :submit is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :submit cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="submit"] instead.

Comment: also, take a look at http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html. Try and replace the bind with a delegate if you have more than one form element.

Comment: a rarely used, but important bit of functionality - I actually had to increase MaxHttpCollectionKeys in order to get it to work.  I suspect the problem has something to do with unobtrusive validation.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be...you're having a problem elsewhere.

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/bq3Jy/) with no delay

Answer (score 0):

chris,

override the submit with something along these lines, not saying it's perfect but gives the UI a chance to collect it's thoughts :):

```
$('input:submit').click(function (e) {
    var outerItem = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function () { outerItem.submit(); }, 10);
    return false;
});
```

disclaimer; not tested, so caveat emptor..

further ref: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: I really would not suggest the use of setTimeout - there is another problem (which I believe to be the filters and DOM) and that should be located.

Comment: yeah -as i said, caveat emptor .. and yup i agree, just giving a wahcky alternative to plug in for a boring rainy day :)